# How to change css of active class of child component, on click of other common component in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, css-selectors

In my html template I have two common component

If I click on app-headers link its active class is applied.After that If i click on sidenavbar's link its active class is applied. At a time I want only one active class be applied between two child component. what changes can be done from parent component so only one components active class is applied.

I tried by :host ::ng-deep in scss , but I am not able to make it conditional. I want this changes be reflected only, when I click on other components . But its ovverriding child components css.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a flag when they click make that as `true` and when other options clicked then make it as `false` and use it in required way. Here's an example below which changes the color based on `colorFlag` to `true` or `false` in `css`:

```
<div class="col-12 text-right" style="{{(colorFlag) ? 'color: red;':'color:blue;'}}"> 
  <!-- Your Code Here -->
</div>
```